# Cannot use ClientIDMode, states missing assembly reference

Tags: c#, asp.net

Error upon build is:

`'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList' does not contain a definition for 'ClientIDMode' and no extension method 'ClientIDMode' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

The code is:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cbNames" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"> 
    <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="&lt;--Select Name--&gt;" /> 
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Name1" /> 
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Name2" /> 
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I am using .NET framework 4.0 as the build framework.

Is there a change to the web.config file that I'd need to make in order to enable .NET to recognise the attribute?

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="cbNames" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="&lt;--Select Name--&gt;" />
        <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Name1" />
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Name2" />
        </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: Sorry about the formatting Adil, but there is the whole DropDownList. It is pretty standard and straightforward, but I think this is a configuration type of issue, not code. Thanks

Comment: Make sure you have framework 4, it need System.Web.UI namespace did you include that?

Comment: Are u sure you're using 4.0? In your Web.Config do you see version for `System.Web` or `System.Web.UI` ?

Comment: Thanks Adil, yes the framework shows 4.0. I guess you mean the reference:
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

Comment: I think I have found the potential solution Yuriy and thanks. I have made a change to the <assemblies> for System.Web.Extensions. It was showing 3.5.0.0 as the version. I have now updated this to 4.0.0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are actually using the 4.0 framework.  Right click on the project and go to properties.  Look at the target framework there and switch it to 4.0 or 4.5

Comment: Thanks Chris, I've checked and the target framework (property pages) is 4.0

Comment: If that's true then it's highly likely that this was a converted project which failed to correctly update all of the references.  Open up your properties window and click on the various `System` references to verify they are pointing to the 4.0 versions.  If not, fix them.

Comment: Will check em out accordingly. Thanks.