# ASP.NET project not building in my Testing machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a running project that I need to modify. I am trying to load the whole project into my Visual Studio 15 CE for modifying. I have got the whole list of files in my Solution explorer and then also the database in SQL manager. When I click execute, it gives an error list! Here is the image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToX0Q.png)

Then In the Browser, I get this message:

```
HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.
Most likely causes:

system.web/identity@impersonate is set to true.

Things you can try:

If the application supports it, disable client impersonation.
If you are certain that it is OK to ignore this error, it can be disabled by setting   system.webServer/validation@validateIntegratedModeConfiguration to false.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     ConfigurationValidationModule
Notification       BeginRequest
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070032
Requested URL      http://localhost:55014    /fanKc9TuE6zuHQVMTPwHWVIHJCM.html
Physical Path      H:\Quoting system files\MGF_LIVE_BACKUP\fanKc9TuE6zuHQVMTPwHWVIHJCM.html
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined
Request Tracing Directory      D:\Old folders\Documents\IISExpress \TraceLogFiles\MGF_LIVE_BACKUP
```

Comment: in regard to the image you've attached, had you recently downgraded the framework in your project?

Comment: ClientIDMode belongs to System.Web.UI namespace on Framework 4 and later but it's missing in Framework 3.5 and raises this error. More information here http://forums.asp.net/t/1785632.aspx?The+type+or+namespace+name+ClientIDMode+does+not+exist+in+the+namespace+System+Web+UI+are+you+missing+an+assembly+reference+ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687011/cannot-use-clientidmode-states-missing-assembly-reference

Comment: What's the .Net framework version of the original project? Open the .csproj file in a notepad and let us know the "ToolsVersion" value.

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont have the csproj file. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

This is an application Pool setting issue..

Try going into IIS and changing the app pool for your application to use classic mode instead of integreted mode.

Alternatively you can add this to your Web.Config:

```
 <system.webServer>
     <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
 </system.webServer>
```